# How could I parse string into Date type "1998/10/01", "1998/1/01" format YYYY/M/D

Tags: mongodb

How could I parse string into Date type "1998/10/01", "1998/1/01" format YYYY/M/D,

the tricky part is in month, this field maybe 2 digit for 10~12 or 1 digit for 1~9.

Is it possible to parse the kind of date string in mongo ?

like `Date("$date_str")`

Comment: What's the purpose of this parsing, do you wish to do convert a field data type from string to Date?

Comment: yes, I need to convert the STRING type into DATE type

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with Javascript.

Assume I have the following document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("553a6abb3614af9afd23310c"),
    "foo" : "bar",
    "date" : "1998/10/01"
}
```

Note that `date` is a string. We can run the following JavaScript in Mongo Shell to update this to become a Date Object.

```
db.test.find().forEach( function(doc) {
   if( typeof doc.date != 'undefined' ) { //There is a date property 
       var doc_date = doc.date.split("/"); //Explode on the `/`
       doc.date = new Date(doc_date[0], doc_date[1], doc_date[2]); //Overwrite current value with Date Object
       db.test.save(doc); //Save this document
   }
});
```

And our document will now have the `Date` object;

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("553a6abb3614af9afd23310c"),
    "foo" : "bar",
    "date" : ISODate("1998-11-01T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Comment: Not sure wether `forEach` lazyloads the data. Otherwise there may be problems for very large result sets.

Comment: I believe cursors use lazy loading - will search

Comment: You need to do `parseInt(doc_date[i])` before you use the array elements as the Date object parameters. A much easier approach would just be creating the Date object with the date string as the parameter e.g `var d1 = new Date("1998/10/01"); console.log(d1); // displays Thu Oct 01 1998 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)` Also `var d2 = new Date("1998/1/01"); console.log(d2); // displays Thu Jan 01 1998 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)`

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to get a date object from such a date string format `YYYY/M/D`; just pass the string as the parameter to the Date object on creation. These two simple tests confirm this:

```
var d1 = new Date("1998/10/01"),
    d2 = new Date("1998/1/01");

console.log(d1); // Thu Oct 01 1998 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
console.log(d2); // Thu Jan 01 1998 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

For relatively small datasets, you can then use the mongo's [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach) cursor method to do an atomic update with the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set) operator  :

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    db.collection.update(
        {"_id": doc._id}, 
        { 
            "$set": {
                "date": new Date(doc.date) 
             } 
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for yours answer.

we should `minus 1` on month, to get the correct Date.

```
db[collection].find().forEach( function(doc) {
   if( typeof doc._id != 'undefined' ) { //There is a date property 
       var doc_date = doc._id.split("/"); //Explode on the `/`
       doc.date = new Date(doc_date[0], doc_date[1]-1, doc_date[2]); //Overwrite current value with Date Object
       doc.date = new Date(doc._id); //Overwrite current value with Date Object
       db[collection].save(doc); //Save this document
   }
});
```